# Como salvar PDF de um site no Azure Functions?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, pdf, microsoft-azure

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação onde terei que fazer um crawler em um site especifico.

A aplicação vai conter um endpoint para uma Azure Function onde o crawler vai fazer a captura.

Até ai tudo certo, porém, vamos ter que salvar evidências que o crawler passou pelo site. Estamos pensando em salvar um PDF com a tela referente a captura, mas, como é especificado na documentação do Azure Functions, o Selenium (que seria uma boa alternativa) ou o PhantomJS não funcionam.

Uma outra abordagem seria baixar o conteudo do site todo em HTML e de alguma forma processar o HTML para gerar um PDF com o que foi visto pelo crawler.

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma biblioteca que funcione no Azure Functions para fazer a captura de alguma URL e salvar em PDF.

Grato.

Comment: Você quer salvar o arquivo físico dentro do Azure Functions? Teria que salvar no Azure Storage, correto?

Answer (score -1):

Você pode usar o [ITextSharp 7](https://itextpdf.com/en/products/itext-7/itext-7-core).

No entanto, essa não é uma tarefa tão simples. Dê uma olhada [neste link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45679233/8843585), nessa resposta no StackOverflow original (use o Google Tradutor se necessário).

Normalmente essas conversões não ficam tão boas quanto se espera.
Porém, se for viável você pode você mesmo construir o pdf usando os métodos do IText. Logicamente não ficará igual ao original também, porém dependendo do conteúdo a ser inserido no pdf, pode servir.

Consulte a documentação do IText [aqui](https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/api-documentation).

Há vários tutoriais pela internet também, como este por exemplo:

[Basic PDF Creation Using iTextSharp - Part I](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/f2e803/basic-pdf-creation-using-itextsharp-part-i/)

O Itext funciona com Azure Functions porque funciona com .NetCore. A maioria das bibliotecas que mexem com essas coisas usam .NetFramework que só compatível com Azure Functions v1.

Para isso é preciso ter atenção na questão de licenças, são as versões mais recentes e pagas do IText que suportam .NetCore. As antigas também são em .NetFrameWork.
Mas existe uma adaptação de terceiros, chamada [iTextSharp.LGPLv2.Core](https://github.com/VahidN/iTextSharp.LGPLv2.Core/). Você pode instalá-la via NuGet.